# Connection to JMS broker failing

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, activemq-classic

I have a Glassfish server (4.1.2) and following [this tutorial](https://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-1/) I have integrated Apache ActiveMQ to the server. Afterwards I developed a standalone Client for messaging according to [this part of the same tutorial](https://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-2/). Finished with that I followed the [last part of this tutorial](https://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-3/) to develop  a MessageDrivenBean listening to the queue used in the steps before.

Everything compiled fine. ActiveMQ is also running. But whenever I deploy the EJB the following is logged in my GF server log:

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
Warning:   RAR8000 : The method setDestinationLookup is not present in the class : org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQActivationSpec
Warning:   RAR7097: No setter method present for the property destinationLookup in the class org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQActivationSpec
Info:   2017-06-06 11:43:00,675 [min-listener(1)] INFO  ActiveMQEndpointWorker         - Starting
Info:   2017-06-06 11:43:00,682 [ad-pool-1; w: 4] INFO  ActiveMQEndpointWorker         - Establishing connection to broker [vm://0.0.0.0:6616]
Info:   WELD-000900: 2.2.13 (Final)
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Info:   AmdMDB was successfully deployed in 5.290 milliseconds.
Info:   2017-06-06 11:43:31,695 [ad-pool-1; w: 4] ERROR ActiveMQEndpointWorker         - Failed to connect to broker [vm://0.0.0.0:6616]: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 0.0.0.0:6616
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 0.0.0.0:6616
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:260)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:273)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter.makeConnection(ActiveMQResourceAdapter.java:132)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker$1.run(ActiveMQEndpointWorker.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 0.0.0.0:6616
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3031)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3047)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.URISupport.parseComposite(URISupport.java:390)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.URISupport.parseComposite(URISupport.java:279)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doCompositeConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:258)
    ... 7 more
Info:   2017-06-06 11:43:31,697 [ad-pool-1; w: 4] ERROR ActiveMQEndpointWorker         - Endpoint will try to reconnect to the JMS broker in 30 seconds
Info:   2017-06-06 11:43:40,060 [jb-thread-pool1] INFO  ActiveMQEndpointWorker         - Stopping
```

The Stopping at the end is due to the undeployment I did, because the same error would come every thirty seconds with the reconnection try.

I am not quite sure, where the error is. The port is 6616 by the way isn't a typo, it is the actual port where ActiveMQ is running because port 61616 is in use by another process.

Can you please give me a hint, on where to search for the mistake?

By the way: When I send a message to the queue with the standalone client, no Exception is thrown (so this seems to be working.) However, I am also unable to send a message via the ActiveMQ Admin console to the server.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html, when using activemq vm tranport, it should be the broker name after "vm://".

If want to use the ip and port, config this way:

```
vm:(broker:(tcp://localhost:6000)?persistent=false)?marshal=false
```

Comment: Okay Thanks that helped. Now the logs say  `Successfully established connection to broker[vm:broker:(tcp://0.0.0.0))]`. And also I am receiving messages. You are a livesaver :)

Comment: Is there a reason why I have to wait approx 1 minute until I receive a message in the server logs from the activemq admin console?

Comment: @FabianSchneider  It doesn't seems normal. But I can't figure out why the 1 min delay at the moment. maybe some very detailed reason.